# How can find if the CDI of my bike is working fine?

Tags: motorcycle, two-stroke, seized-engine, engine-knock

I have a 2001 Yamaha RX 135 2 stroke motor bike and have installed an aftermarket performance CDI which claimed to give me better performance and RPM rev.
But since I have installed it I seem to feel a significant loss of torque specially at lower ranges.
This is a bit of problem when I have to drive up a slope or start my bike on an inclined angle.
The CDI guys said that I might have to tune bike for rich fuel mix but am not sure how do I do it or if that would solve the problem.

Comment: Worth trying to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Of course you could remove the aftermarket cdi and see if it improves as another test.

Comment: Alright that what the only thing that came to my mind ,will try this way and update.

Comment: I know its late but yes the issue was the cdi I think it was not meant to run/fit optimally on a stock bike, the old cdi works fine and the torque/punch feels better.